# select parameter in sql data source

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GSProjectConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table] where Owner like '%@username%' ">
             <SelectParameters>
                 <asp:Parameter Name="username" Type="String"/>
             </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The above is my code wherein i am trying to use a variable username which is defined in .cs file.

It does not take the value of username.

Where am I going wrong ?

Any idea anyone ?

Comment: Well - run it - does it work??

Comment: No,it  doesn't.It does not take the value of username.

Comment: try change the SelectCommand to  SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table] where Owner like @username">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it as

```
 SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table] where Owner like @username
```

when you set parameter value you can add the '%%' as below

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["username"].DefaultValue = string.Format("%{0}%", paramvalue);
```

Comment: there is a difference between @username and '@username', 2nd one is no longer a parameter, it consider as string value.

Comment: I initially tried data binding actually,something like <%#username%> but that did not work either.